# Is "mom laughed and called" grammatically wrong here?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> Just then, he heard his mom laughed and called, "Come here!"

I think **..laughed and called..**. is incorrect.

Would it be better changing it to **...laughing and calling...**?

Thanks.

Comment: who is doing the calling, "he" or "his mom"?

Comment: He himself did the calling.

Comment: Then, since the verb pair to describe "his actions" is **heard and called** it is important that those are the same tense, and not **laughed and called** / **laughing and calling**

Comment: I see. But what if his mother did the calling?

Comment: who did the laughing? If it's his mom, then it should be _He heard his mom laugh_ (not _laughed_). If it's him laughing, we need commas: _He heard his mom, laughed, and called ..._

Comment: Why do we use laugh instead of laughed?  I appreciate if you could explain since I don't really get it. :)

Comment: Verbs of perception such as "hear", "see", etc. usually take a bare-infinival clause as a complement. The -ing version is also possible but that will have an imperfective interpretation.